# FCM push notifications to Chrome while killed

Tags: android, firebase, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem receiving push notifications to an Android Chrome PWA when no Chrome apps are running.  I can reproduce this with 3 different public web-push examples.  The first question is should a web-push example work the same as a PWA with web-push? That is, should a web push on Android be able to be received and display a notification even if the browser is not running. [Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/faq) seem to say yes.  Why does the test below not confirm this.

**Problem Description**

The problem does not affect Firefox.  There are other posts that have attributed similar behavior to the payload of the message (data and/or notification) or the battery optimization settings.  Altering these variables doesn't seem to improve my situation.  Here's a method for reproducing the problem using one of the online examples (Thanks to Carlos for pulling this together..see code [here](https://github.com/guerrerocarlos/serverless-web-push-notifications)).

**Reproduction Steps**

1. Open up Carlos [demo](https://x79n1d1ajl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/index.html) on your Android phone.  Accept the notification permissions and ensure that you can send yourself a notification.
2. Open up the same page on another machine.  Ensure that you can send your phone a push notification using the "Send to all subscribers immediatelly"[sic] function.
3. Kill all the Chrome apps on your android device.  To be on the safe side, kill all your running apps cause I've found it not obvious what's using chrome and I think this has confused a lot of previous posts/answers.
4. Repeat step 2 on the second machine.  You should not get the notification on Chrome.
5. Once you're convinced the message is not coming, open any Chrome app.  After a few seconds, you should receive the notifications.

Repeat all of the above with Firefox on Android and you will get the notification in step 4.

You can run a similar tests [here](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/) or [here](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html).

Comment: Possible related Chrome bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935931

Comment: I believe this is resolved in Chrome Dev 74

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs related to this issue on Chrome.  The problem is resolved in Chrome Dev 74 which is due to be stable on Apr 23, 2019.